# Create a script to turn wifi off on shutdown

Tags: wifi, script, shutdown

Is there anyway to create a script that will automatically shut down the WiFi when I power down my machine?
Maybe in Automator?

Comment: Would you consider turning off WiFi when starting up? The end result should be equivalent, be more reliable, and not risk blocking/slowing the shut down process.

Comment: Didn't tested any of those, but you can combine [How to Run an AppleScript When Switching to Battery Power](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-01-28-how-to-run-an-applescript-when-switching-to-battery-power/index.html) and [Turn AirPort on or off with AppleScript](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070728102702656) in order to get what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I guess just turning it on and off with the switch on the top bar makes more sense than adding another process to the shutdown.